# Angular - How to validate based on the visible div element

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

In my Angular-13, I want to Show/Hide div element using ng-select dropdown. I have this code:

enum

```
export const CHARGE_REQUIRED_DATA = [
  {
    'key': 0,
    'value': 'False'
  },
  {
    'key': 1,
    'value': 'True'
  }
]

export const CHARGE_MODE_DATA = [
  {
    'key': 1,
    'value': 'Fixed'
  },
  {
    'key': 2,
    'value': 'Percentage'
  }
]
```

Then in the component, I have this code:

**component.ts**

```
import { CHARGE_MODE_DATA } from 'src/app/core/enum/chargemode';
import { CHARGE_REQUIRED_DATA } from 'src/app/core/enum/chargerequired';

export class TransCreateComponent implements OnInit {

  createTransForm!: FormGroup;
  selectedChargeRequired:any;
  selectedChargeMode:any;

  constructor(
    private fb: FormBuilder,
    ) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.createTrans();
    this.chargeRequiredData = CHARGE_REQUIRED_DATA;
    this.chargeModeData = CHARGE_MODE_DATA;
  }

  createTrans() {
    this.createTransForm = this.fb.group({
      ChargeRequired: ['', [Validators.required]],
      ChargeMode: [''],
      ChargePercent: ['', RxwebValidators.numeric({allowDecimal:true,isFormat:true})],
      ChargeValue: ['', RxwebValidators.numeric({allowDecimal:true,isFormat:true})],
    });
  }
```

component.html:

```
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="ChargeRequired">Charges Required<span style="color:red;">*</span></label>
      <ng-select [items]="chargeRequiredData"
        [selectOnTab]="true"
        [searchable]="true"
        bindValue="key"
        bindLabel="value"
        placeholder="Select Charge Required"
        [multiple]="false"
        [clearable]="true"
        [(ngModel)]="selectedChargeRequired"
        formControlName="ChargeRequired">
      </ng-select>
      <div *ngIf="fc['ChargeRequired'].touched && fc['ChargeRequired'].invalid" class="alert alert-danger">
        <div *ngIf="fc['ChargeRequired'].errors && fc['ChargeRequired'].errors['required']">The field is required!</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <ng-container *ngIf="selectedChargeRequired == '1'">
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="ChargeRequired">Charge Mode</label>
        <ng-select [items]="chargeModeData"
          [selectOnTab]="true"
          [searchable]="true"
          bindValue="key"
          bindLabel="value"
          placeholder="Select Charge Required"
          [multiple]="false"
          [clearable]="true"
          [(ngModel)]="selectedChargeMode"
          formControlName="ChargeMode">
        </ng-select>
      </div>
    </div>
  </ng-container>

  <ng-container *ngIf="selectedChargeMode == '2'">
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="ChargePercent">Charge Percent</label>
        <input type="text" formControlName="ChargePercent" class="form-control" id="ChargePercent" placeholder="Enter Charge Percent">
      </div>
    </div>
  </ng-container>
  <ng-container *ngIf="selectedChargeMode == '1'">
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="ChargeValue">Charge Value</label>
        <input type="text" formControlName="ChargeValue" class="form-control" id="ChargeValue" placeholder="Enter Charge Value">
      </div>
    </div>
  </ng-container>
```

I am using ng-select dropdown.

It is expected that:

1. On ChargeRequired select, If selectedChargeRequired is 1 then ChargeMode should be visible.
2. If ChargeMode is 1, ChargeValue should be visible and if is 2 then ChargePercent should be visible.

The logic above is working.

How do make the validations for **ChargeMode, ChargePercent and ChargeValue** to be applicable only when they are visible. **and also each of them should be required when visible**?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the required validator conditionally on the form control and clear it off also. See this example.

Inside oninit subscribe for watching changes on your formcontrol first.

```
 this.createTransForm.get('ChargeRequired').valueChanges
                     .subscribe(value => this.toggleValidity(value));
```

Then define `toggleValidity` method to apply or take off the validation

```
toggleValidity(selectedChargeRequired : string): void {    
    if(selectedChargeRequired === '1') {
        const chargeModeCntrl = this.createTransForm.get('ChargeMode');    
        chargeModeCntrl.setValidators(Validators.required);
        chargeModeCntrl.updateValueAndValidity();            
    }
    else {
        this.createTransForm.controls["ChargeMode"].setErrors(null);
        this.createTransForm.controls["ChargeMode"].clearValidators();
        this.createTransForm.controls["ChargeMode"].updateValueAndValidity();
    }
}
```

Comment: I just this error:     Object is possibly 'null'.     and it highlights   
      this.createTransForm.get('ChargeRequired').valueChanges